# Different Build behavior between VS2019 as Admin versus as User

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, npm, yarnpkg

I'm developing a web application in Visual Studio '19 and I'm experiencing odd behavior depending on whether I run VS regularly or as admin.

The front-end is a .NET Core 2.0 Web App that launches a React app.   We're using a Yarn script to run `parcel-bundler` in Build mode.

When I build my front-end project in a regular VS2019 instance, this process works and the app builds successfully.

However, when I build the front end from an Admin VS session, I get a large number of errors, all spurring from parcel-bundler, and all with the same error message: `Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:`

The Yarn output provides a little more information:
`Parser "parcel-plugin-typed-css-modules\src\asset.js" failed to initialize when processing asset "[our_code]"`

Does anyone have any ideas?  My coworkers do not experience this and we haven't yet found any notable differences between our development environments.